# My app is crashing when I call my function by pressing a button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple gallery app. When I try this code:

```
public void previousTap(View view){
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view;
    if (img.getTag() == "img_one") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_five);
        img.setTag("img_five");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "img_two") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_one);
        img.setTag("img_one");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "img_three") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_two);
        img.setTag("img_two");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "img_four") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_three);
        img.setTag("img_three");
    } else if (img.getTag() == "img_five") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_four);
        img.setTag("img_four");
    }
}
```

When I run my project and install the app and click on the previous button, my app crashes. Why? Also, is there any way to get the tag of an imageview in activity_main.xml rather than typing "ImageView img = (ImageView) view;"(Only if it is wrong)?

The error I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wali.photoframegallery, PID: 6166
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6603)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6576)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26090)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6760)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6603) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6576) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:780) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26090) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:235) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6760) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
        at com.wali.photoframegallery.MainActivity.nextTap(MainActivity.java:32)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6603) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6576) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:780) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26090) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:235) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6760) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
```

**EDIT:**
I tried changing this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) view;
```

To this:

```
View img = (View) view;
```

It gave me no errors, but there is no more functionality. What's wrong now?

Comment: please post the stack trace, error msgs etc...

Comment: why do you use for loop here? And add stack trace, why exactly your app crashes. Probably it is NPE, but we can't really help you guessing what is it

Comment: As a side note, the `for()` is unnecessary, or each `if` block shouldn't have a `break`.

Comment: I want to break the function when a specific statement is true, how can I do that?

Comment: @WaliullahBukhari, there is no case that more then one if statement gonna be passed

Comment: But, when you'll use it without the `for` loop, only with `if`, you won't need `break` anymore.

Comment: Your problem - `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView`. You're trying to cast a Button as ImageView. Match your XML with your code.

Comment: Also, the error is in the `nextTap()`, check the line no 39 of your `MainActivity` as in your stack trace `nextTap(MainActivity.java:39)`

Answer (score 0):

You can see your problem in next line: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView`
of your stack trace. You can try to cast view in AppCompatButton, or change AppCompatButton to ImageView in your layout

Comment: That is the problem, I am trying to access the current image from its tag. I have even mentioned it in the answer, is there any way I can access an image from main_activity.xml from its tag?

Comment: public void previousTap(View view) - here your view is not an ImageView! It is AppCompatButton. No way you can cast AppCompatButton to ImageView (that what you trying to do here:  ImageView img = (ImageView) view;)

Comment: @WaliullahBukhari now you don't even need this cast: View img = (View) view;, because you can simply use view) You know, your question was about why your app is crashing. I think I answered this question. Why do you lost your functionaluty? Dificult to say, because I don't see any logic, I see only one method, so I have no possibility to understand  what is going wrong